# Routing and checkboxes update from rails 1.x.x to 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, railscasts

Just was checking this episode by Ryan Bates (http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) and it seems that Rails 3.2.x has different setup.

Thus `map.resources :tasks, :collection => { :complete => :put }` does not produce expected result, as it drops an issue that `complete_tasks_path` does not exist. Could you please let me know how to customise routing in this particular situation?

Also seems that `check_box_tag` requires different attributes other than Ryan puts in there. AS it writes back `unexpected kEND...`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please ask one question per question. If you're having some problem with `check_box_tag`, please ask a separate question from your question on routing.

Comment: Done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584343/rails-3-2-8-upgrade-checkboxes-from-rails-1-x-x-to-3-2-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the following which defines a new "completed" action on the collection, accessible at `/tasks/completed`.

Here are three ways of adding an additional action on the collection

```
resources :tasks do 
  put :completed, :on => :collection

  # --- OR ---

  collection do
    put :completed
    # additional collection action here ...
  end

  # --- OR ---

  collection { put :completed }
end
```

This will define a `completed_tasks_path` method, and route to the `completed` action of your `TasksController`.

Comment: Yup, I need PUT, as I'm going to update all collection of element, Thanks