# Rails 3.2.8. Upgrade checkboxes from Rails 1.x.x to 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, railscasts

Just was checking [this episode by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) and it seems that Rails 3.2.x has different setup.

Seems that `check_box_tag` requires different attributes other than Ryan puts in there. AS it writes back `unexpected kEND...` to `<%= check_box_tag "task_ids[]", task.id %>`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your error is unrelated to your use of `check_box_tag`.

"`unexpected kEND`" indicates an unexpected end-of-file, meaning you've opened a block or other nested structure somewhere and failed to close it. Probably a `do` or an `if` with no matching `end`.